# Is protractor Angular's new scenario runner?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I heard recently that, Angular is switching to [Protractor](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor) as the new end to end testing tool, is my understanding correct? I cloned and looked at the sample. I am able to run jasmine-node to see all the tests run fine.  I am able to follow the example code, but just curious, Is there any write up available on this? I did not find any good documentation on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the AngularJS 1.2 and Beyond meetup last night they talked about Protractor and said that they are migrating all of their end to end tests to Protractor. It sounded like this is in the early stages but is the direction they are going. The slides are at: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1WHCcp3G3HxoE7b_ut_ERKJF4zQK_P4qFlESjE2E9AUQ/edit and I assume the video will be available in a couple of days. Here's the link to the meetup:

http://www.meetup.com/AngularJS-MTV/events/120927882/

btw, there was a ton of really interesting info in the meetup -- well worth the watch.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is since AngularJS 1.2. As you may see here, protractor is now part of the Angular's GitHub repository:
https://github.com/angular/protractor

You can start reading here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md