# can I use karma to test page interaction like drag & drop?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, testing, drag-and-drop, karma-runner

I'm evaluating end to end testing of a MEAN stack app. There's a few critical spots in the app where drag and drop (via a directive) is used. I can't find any information about using karma to test this. Is it possible? If not, what library would you recommend?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, Angular comes bundled with e2e testing that can be run via Karma. The [angular-seed application](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) is a good example of a project structure that includes both e2e and unit tests. From the project home page:

> **End to end testing**
>
> Angular ships with a baked-in end-to-end test runner that understands
>   angular, your app and allows you to write your tests with jasmine-like
>   BDD syntax.
>
> Requires a webserver, node.js + `./scripts/web-server.js` or your
>   backend server that hosts the angular static files.
>
> Check out the [end-to-end runner's documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) for more info.
>
> - create your end-to-end tests in `test/e2e/scenarios.js`
> - serve your project directory with your http/backend server or node.js +
>     `scripts/web-server.js`
> - to run do one of:
>
>   - open `http://localhost:port/test/e2e/runner.html` in your browser
>   - run the tests from console with [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) via `scripts/e2e-test.sh` or `script/e2e-test.bat`

Also, it should be noted that apparently the [Angular team will be replacing this current e2e setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052908/is-protractor-angulars-new-scenario-runner) with [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. However I don't feel like this answers my question about drag and drop. The best explanation of karma/ng e2e testing that I've seen is here: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html. But nothing about drag/drop.

Comment: To clarify, what you're really asking is, "How do I write Angular e2e tests specifically for drag-and-drop behavior?" Is that correct?

Comment: Right. I think I can use karma to test the directive, but it appears that I can't use it to test the actual behavior on the page. Casper looks like my best bet so that's the direction I'm going. It appears that Karma can't do this.

Comment: [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) (mentioned in my answer above) [appears to be able to test drag-and-drop behavior](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/123), as it's simply a wrapper for Selenium WebDriver. [Here's an example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/fb46ec9bcd568510248831f11d43d0e2398cc606). Best of luck on whichever direction you choose!